# Python overwriting lines in console

Tags: python, multithreading

I am attempting to learn about concurrent programming with python.  I have a simple script made as an example to show you what I am attempting to do here.  Basically what is happening is some of the output is overwriting lines in the console so I am missing part of the output.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
def dostuff(th):
    for x in range(8):
        lock.acquire()
        print(th, ": loop", x)
        lock.release()
        
def run():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    pool.map(dostuff, inputs)
    print('end')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some of the output:

```
>>> run()
2 : loop 0
2 : loop 1
2 : loop 2
2 : loop 3
>>> run()
3 : loop 0
3 : loop 1
3 : loop 2
3 : loop 3
>>> run()
end
```

Here is some of the expected output:

```
>>> run()
2 : loop 0
3 : loop 1
1 : loop 1
4 : loop 2
>>> run()
end
```

Basically I want to show concurrency. Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some of the output you're talking about, and then additionally add what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: On windows your code only produces errors - using linux? And my expected output would be quite different.

Comment: Yes I am using ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved.  Executed the script through Geany and it seems to be working perfectly.  Thanks for all your support.